# Prove inequality using Mean Value Theorem 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

$|\cos ^2(b) - \cos^2(a)| > \frac{1}{4}|b-a|$ for all $a,b$ within $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{3})$ where $a$ is not equal to $b$. I have done a few other examples and proved them correctly using MVT but this is causing me difficulty.

Comment: Why `complex-analysis`? Why `proof-verification`?

Comment: Mean Value Theorem is in Complex analysis course, Proof-verification was a misclick. Also was no tag for Mean value theorem to be seen.

Comment: $\cos^2b-\cos^2a=\frac12(\cos2b-\cos2a)=-\sin(2c)(b-a)$ and then find a lower bound on $\sin 2c$ in the given interval. This may seem complicated, but is all real analysis, not complex numbers here.

Comment: Why $1/4?$ Im getting $\sqrt 3/2.$ And what is MVT 2?