# Prove the following inequality using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

First off, I've seen a couple questions similar to this one (different inequalities, same principle) but didn't really understand the answers. 
Here are a couple of those questions:

[Prove inequality using Mean Value Theorem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783360/prove-inequality-using-mean-value-theorem-2)

[Prove inequality using Mean Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308466/prove-inequality-using-mean-value-theorem) [Mean Value theorem problem?(inequality)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618525/mean-value-theorem-probleminequality)

$$1 + 2x < e^{2x} < (1-2x)^{-1}, \ \forall \  \textrm{x} \in \ \ ] 0,1/2 [$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the Mean Value Theorem to prove inequalities, remember the conclusion of the MVT:
$$
    \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(t)
$$
for some $t$ between $a$ and $b$.  Replacing $b$ by a variable $x$, and applying some algebra, we get
$$
    f(x) = f(a) + f'(t)(x-a)
$$
The case $a=0$ is particularly useful; it says:
$$
    f(x) = f(0) + f'(t)x
$$
for some $t$ with $0 < t < x$.  If you can give upper and/or lower bounds for $f'(t)$, then you have an equality for $f(x)$ in terms of $x$.

Your example suggests $f(x) = e^{2x}$.  Since $f'(t) = 2e^{2t}$, and $e^{2t} \geq 1$ for all $t\geq 0$, we know $f'(t) \geq 2$.  So
$
    e^{2x} > 1 + 2x
$.

What about the other part of the inequality?  $e^{2x} < (1-2x)^{-1}$ doesn't look like it fits the pattern above.  But again with some algebra,
$$
    e^{2x} < \frac{1}{1-2x} \implies e^{-2x} > 1 - 2x
$$
and now you might see how to adapt the previous case.

Comment: Can you explain the trick to switch the e^-2x with (1 / 1 - 2x)

Comment: I got it now, and was able to do the second one. Thanks!